# columnas perdidas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una enorme duda, agradecería mucho si me pudieran ayudar con este problema, tengo un DataFrame base, el cual seccioné y operé las columnas de la siguiente forma:

`df_1 = pd.DataFrame(bd)`
`df_APRT = df_1.iloc[:, 0:5]`
`df_CPOT = df_APRT.copy()`
`df_CPOT = df_CPOT[df_CPOT['Peso (w) de muestra_APRT'].notna()]`
`df_CPOT['AGL_APRT'] = (2.56*df_CPOT['mL NAOH utilizados_APRT']) / df_CPOT['Peso (w) de muestra_APRT']`
`df_CPOT = df_CPOT.copy().round(3)`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este me genera un df que concateno con otros df con operaciones similares de la siguiente manera

`df_resumen = pd.concat([df_CPOT,df_CPOA,df_PKOT,df_PKOA,df_APCF,df_ACF],axis=1)`\

Pero al querer remplazar los NaN por CEROS (0):

`df_resumen1 = df.isnull()*1`
`df_resumen1= df.fillna('0')`

me borra las columnas que creadas con las operaciones (AGL_APRT)

[image: así]

Answer (score 0):

entre mi búsqueda anterior en foros encontré este modo de remplazar los valores NaN por 0:

`df.replace(np.nan, 0)`

ahora el código funciona perfecto, de igual manera si me comentan porqué pasaba eso les agradecería.

Comment: El método `fillna` sirve para cambiar todos los `NaN` por algún valor.